# How to perform multiple regression analysis with a small sample size? (n=20)

Tags: multiple-regression, sample-size

I have a sample of 20 years, I want to perform multiple regression analysis to estimate economic growth. I have 9 independent variables, but because my sample is small i get insignificant results. I do not have data to maken it a sample of 100 years or anything near that. What can I do? Can I incorporate the sample size into my problem? How do I enter a sample size in SPSS?

Comment: What kind of data is is that you have? I.e. what are the variables and how are they measured?

Comment: "but because my sample is small i get insignificant results." This is serendipitiously correct, since given a large enough sample size, you would find statistically significant effects, even if they weren't significant significant. This is an issue of power. With $n=20$, you don't have enough power to detect even significant significant effect sizes.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you cannot make your results significant when the amount of your data is limited. The calculation of your p-value has taken into account your sample size n. One thing you can try is model selection, in which you assume you don't need all 9 independent variables .A small portion of them will explain the majority of the variability in your response.
  It is the kind of techniques used when n << p i.e when the number of observations < the number of covariates. There are different type of model selection methods such as Lasso and Elastic Net, which are implemented in recent version of SPSS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Lasso_method
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization

Answer (score 1):

you don't enter sample size into SPSS, it'll know it when you enter you data: it's the number of observations.

with N=20, and 9 variables you need to estimate 9+intercept+error variance=11 parameters. you can barely have one parameter in the model. often the rule of thumb is 20 observations per parameter. unless you're dealing with a very stable physical phenomenon, there's no way you're going to get help from statistics alone in such a model.

example of a very stable physical model: you got 20 packs of eggs, each with 10 eggs. your dependent variable is the weight of a egg pack, 10 independent variables are weights of each egg starting from the one on top left corner. i bet that if you run this experiment all betas will be $beta_i=1$, they'll be significant, as well as the intercept too. So, the intercept would be the weight of the packaging.

[image]

So, the hope is not lost if you're not in social sciences, but in manufacturing or natural sciences.